# JQuery slideDowns stop when an onclick is clicked too fast

Tags: jquery, onclick, slidedown

I have a list of items that a user can add to by clicking an "Add" button. It adds a new div on top of the list, which slides down (JQuery's $().slideDown();). The problem is, if the user clicks the add button too fast, the slide stops and never finishes.

Here's a short example of what I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/2RqmU/44/ click on "Click here" really fast.

How can I ensure that the animation doesn't stop, or at least disable the onclick until the animation is done?

Comment: Can't you just change the slideDown delay to 100ms? using your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2RqmU/46/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the entire contents of the target `div` on each click. Instead, you can just append/prepend individual elements. This sorts out your animation problem:

```
var id = 0;

//click
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    //Add a new div on top in content
    var pre = "<div id='foo" + id + "' class='dynamicdiv'>hello " + id + "</div>";
    $("#content").prepend(pre);

    //Slide it down and update ID
    $("#foo" + id).slideDown(300);
    id++;
});​
```

see the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2RqmU/56/).

Comment: Thanks you are my hero -- I knew what I was doing felt really weird.

Comment: To explain what was going wrong.

`var pre = $("#content").html();`

Was grabbing a snapshot of your content at that exact - half-animated - moment. Then you re-inserted it as new content, freezing it in place.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little change but that will work

```
var id = 0;

$("#clickme").click(function() {
    //Add a new div on top in content
    $("#content").prepend("<div id='foo" + id + "' class='dynamicdiv'>hello " + id + "</div>");

    //Slide it down and update ID
    $("#foo" + id).slideDown(300);
    id++;
});​
```

Comment: If you want them to go into sequence just change $("#content").prepend to $("#content").append

Answer (score 1):

Nice and clean!
http://jsfiddle.net/2RqmU/59/

Final Version:

HTML

```
<div id="clickme">CLICK HERE</div>
<div id="content">            
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var id = 0;

//click
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    //Add a new div on top in content
    $('<div/>')
        .attr({
            "id" : "foo" + id                
        })
        .addClass("dynamicdiv")
        .html("Hello " + id)
        .prependTo('#content')
        .slideDown(300);

    id++;
});
```

CSS

```
div#clickme {
    background-color: #5e1d1d;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.dynamicdiv {
    background-color: #5c8591;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Oh nice, that is clean! I just started JQuery yesterday so I'm still learning all this.. That is really helpful to know you can format it that easily